# Stored Function Variables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, function, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I am trying to create a stored function in MySQL but when I try to run the function it does't see the variable 'InterimAPI'

Code is as follows:

```
 DELIMITER $$

 Create function 
InterimAPI_Math(test_subject char(100), grade
int(2), GradeTableValue decimal(5,2)) 

Returns decimal(6,2) Not Deterministic


 Begin
    Declare IterimAPI decimal(10,2);

    if test_subject = 'Math' AND Grade = 3 THEN
        SET @@InterimAPI = (10.9*(GradeTableValue - 253.9)) + 1000;
    elseif test_subject = 'MATH' AND GRADE = 4 THEN
        SET @@InterimAPI = (10.8*(GradeTableValue -253.4)) + 1000;
    elseif test_subject = 'MATH' AND GRDE = 5 THEN
        SET @@InterimAPI = (10.1*(GradeTableValue - 250.3)) + 1000;
    elseif test_subject = 'MATH' AND GRADE = 6 THEN
        SET @@InterimAPI = (9.4*(GradeTableValue - 246.3)) + 1000;
    elseif test_subject = 'MATH' AND GRADE = 7 THEN
        SET @@InterimAPI = (8.4*(GradeTableValue - 240.2)) + 1000;
    elseif test_subject = 'MATH' AND GRADE = 8 THEN
        SET @@InterimAPI = (8.4*(GradeTableValue - 239.8)) + 1000;
    elseif test_subject = 'Algebra I' AND GRADE = 'EOI' THEN
        SET InterimAPI = (17.4*(GradeTableValue - 71.2)) + 1000;
    END IF;

Return (InterimAPI);
```

END

Also slightly confused as to what belongs in the parameters. Is it the information from the table that you want input into the function or something else?

Comment: I don't think the @@ is required. Change all @@InterimAPI to InterimAPI and see whether that helps.

Comment: Tried that but its still giving me the same error

Comment: Also a spelling mistake in the Declare - **IterimAPI** not **InterimAPI**

Comment: btw. just use one `IF test_subject = 'Math' THEN` and inside use a [**CASE**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)

Comment: Is there any reason why I would use a CASE instead an elseif? just wondering?

Comment: Also note that your final elseif will cause problems - you have declared grade as int, but comparing it to 'EOI' which cannot be converted to int. **AND** spelling in the 3rd check **GRDE** not **GRADE**. And a default value would be useful.